# Is there a way to have SQL server validate object references in Stored Procs?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, typechecking

The following code executes fine in SQL Server

```
create proc IamBrokenAndDontKnowIt as
select * from tablewhichdoesnotexist
```

Of course if I try to run it, it fails with

> Invalid object name 'tablewhichdoesnotexist'.

Is there any way to compile or verify that Stored Proc are valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just discovered that VS2010 with database projects will do syntax and name reference checking. Seems like the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC dbo.My_Proc
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

You'll need to capture the error(s) somehow, but it shouldn't take much to put together a quick utility application that takes advantage of this for finding invalid stored procedures.

I haven't used this extensively, so I don't know if there are any side-effects to look out for.

Comment: Nope. It will return empty resultsets and any updates/inserts/etc. will not be run. I also just ran a quick test on DDL (DROP TABLE) and using dynamic SQL and neither of those ran either. The UPDATE statement just returned a count of 0 rows affected.

Answer (score 1):

You used to get a warning message when you tried to create a stored procedure like that.  It would say:

> Cannot add rows to sysdepends for the current stored procedure because it depends on the missing object 'dbo.nonexistenttable'. The stored procedure will still be created.

For some reason I'm not getting it now, I'm not sure if it's been changed or if there's just some setting that turns the warning on or off.  Regardless, this should give you a hint as to what's happening here.

SQL Server *does* track dependencies, but only dependencies which *actually exist*.  Unfortunately, none of the dependency tricks like `sp_depends` or `sp_MSdependencies` will work here, because you're looking for *missing* dependencies.

Even if we could hypothetically come up with a way to check for these missing dependencies, it would still be trivial to concoct something to defeat the check:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Broken
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM NonExistentTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

You could also try parsing for expressions like "FROM xxx", but it's easy to defeat that too:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Broken2
AS

SELECT *
FROM
    NonExistentTable
```

There really isn't any reliable way to *examine* a stored procedure and check for missing dependencies without actually running it.

You can use `SET FMTONLY ON` as Tom H mentions, but be aware that this changes the way that the procedure is "run".  It won't catch some things.  For example, there's nothing stopping you from writing a procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Broken3
AS

DECLARE @TableName sysname

SELECT @TableName = Name
FROM SomeTable
WHERE ID = 1

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Let's assume you have a real table named `SomeTable` and a real row with `ID = 1`, but with a `Name` that doesn't refer to any table.  You won't get any errors from this if you wrap it inside a `SET FMTONLY ON/OFF` block.

That may be a contrived problem, but `FMTONLY ON` does other weird things like executing every branch of an `IF`/`THEN`/`ELSE` block, which can cause other unexpected errors, so you have to be very specific with your error-handling.

The only truly reliable way to test a procedure is to actually run it, like so:

```
BEGIN TRAN

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC usp_Broken
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Error'
END CATCH

ROLLBACK
```

This script will run the procedure in a transaction, take some action on error (in the `CATCH`), and immediately roll back the transaction.  Of course, even this may have some side-effects, like changing the `IDENTITY` seed if it inserts into a table (successfully).  Just something to be aware of.

To be honest, I wouldn't touch this problem with a 50-foot pole.

Comment: afaik you get the warning only if one sp calls another (not yet existing) sp. I have never seen this warning in case of non-existing tables or views.

Answer (score 1):

No (but read on, see last line)

It's by design: [Deferred Name Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(SQL.90).aspx)

[Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html) raised an [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=260762#tabs) for `SET STRICT_CHECKS ON`

The connect request has a [workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=260762#tabs) (not tried myself):

> Use check execution plan. The only
>   weakness is that you may need
>   permissions to see the execution plan
>   first

Answer (score 0):

You could run `sp_depends` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx) and use that information to query the information schema (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) to see if all objects exist. From what I read here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214346(SQL.80).aspx) you only need to check referenced tables, which is doable.

Comment: I think that sp_depends will only work for objects that actually exist. A quick test on my server shows no dependencies reported when I reference an invalid table.

Comment: Tom H. thanks. I guess I should have tested it instead of assuming. Sorry for the red herring.

Answer (score 0):

You could check information_schema.tables to check whether a table exist or not and then execute the code

here is quickly slung function to check

```
 create function fnTableExist(@TableName varchar(64)) returns int as
    begin
        return (select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_name=@tableName and Table_type='Base_Table')
    end

go        

    if dbo.fnTableExist('eObjects') = 0 
        print 'Table exist'
    else
        print 'no suchTable'
```

like wise you can check for existance of Stored procs / functions in

.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.Routine_name  for th name of the Stored proc/function

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2005 or higher, you can test a stored procedure using transactions and try/catch:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
  EXEC (@storedproc)
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

The algorithm to test all stored procedures in a database is a bit more complicated, as you need to workaround SSMS restrictions if you have many SPs which return many result sets. See my [blog for complete solution](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/checking-ms-sql-server-stored-procedures/).