# Why stored procedure is being re-created though the table it uses is deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I faced a weird problem while deleting old tables and stored procedures from SQL Server 2012 database. The whole idea was to delete old tables (100+) first and then re-create all the stored procedures. So, if any stored procedure contains reference of deleted table it simple won't be created. But surprisingly, all the stored procedures are being created even though table doesn't exists!

I have tried restarting SQL Server instance, refreshing local schema, tried `WITH RECOMPILE` option as well as some `DBCC` command, but nothing works.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve the issue?

Comment: How did you attempt to recreate the SPs?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015078/is-there-a-way-to-have-sql-server-validate-object-references-in-stored-procs)

Comment: And from the question that @shibormot links to, it's worth following the link from gbn's answer to [this connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/260762/add-optional-checks-for-more-robust-development#tabs) and voting on it

Answer (score 2):

Without table existance, stored procedure still can be created, just when you run them, exception will throw. So, you can't rely on table to decide if create stored procedure or not.

What you can do is, after you delete all those 100+ old tables, you can check your stored procedure dependency, you can use SSMS GUI, just right click the stored procedure, and view dependency, then select view [Objects on which [..] depends], then you can know which stored procedure has unresolved entity, then you can delete the stored procedure.

Comment: I have already tried it but this way I have to go one by one with all stored procedures and it simply is not feasible. Is there any way to find the un-resolved dependencies using query? I read a post https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008. However, it's far from perfect.

Comment: SQL Prompt has a Find Invalid Objects feature that you might want to try. This lists the invalid objects, allows you to highlight them in the Object Explorer where you can delete them. More detail here: http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/SQL_Prompt/help/5.3/SP_Finding_invalid_objects